Closed form for $\sum \left (\pm a_1 \pm a_2 \pm \dots \pm a_n\right )^\ell$
I realized that if you take the $2^n$ quantities
$$\pm a_1 \pm a_2 \pm \dots \pm a_n$$
and consider the sum of their squares, then the product terms cancel out nicely to give
$$\sum \left (\pm a_1 \pm a_2 \pm \dots \pm a_n\right )^2 = 2^n \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$$
since the cross terms are coming in pairs.
However this is not the case for higher order sums since the cross terms don't behave so nicely anymore. Irrespective of that, does the sum
$$\sum \left (\pm a_1 \pm a_2 \pm \dots \pm a_n\right )^{2\ell}$$
have a nice closed form for any integer $\ell$. Can we at least find a closed form for the cases $\ell=2$ and $\ell=3$?

Can you please share your attempts for $\ell=3$ and the first values of $n$? (better in your post than in a comment). If I am not mistaken, it is always $0$ for $\ell$ odd.

Clearly $0$ for $\ell$ odd.

@AnneBauval I wanted to write something and ended up writing something else, I will make an edit.

@ThomasAndrews please check the edit

The multinomial theorem
$$
(x_1 + x_2  + \cdots + x_n)^l
 = \sum_{\begin{array}{c} k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n=l \\ k_1, k_2, \cdots, k_n \geq 0\end{array}} {l \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n}
  \prod_{t=1}^n x_t^{k_t}
$$
tells how often terms of the structure $ \prod_{t=1}^n x_t^{k_t}$ arise. Let´s look at several $l$, taking into account the constraint $ k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n=l$.
For $l=2$ you can have such products of the form $x_i^2$ or $x_i x_j$. Then summing these terms gives $\sum_ {x_i = \pm a_i} x_i^2 = 2 a_i^2$, whereas $\sum_ {x_i = \pm a_i} x_i \sum_ {x_j = \pm a_j} x_j = 0$, which gives your result.
For $l=3$ you can have $x_i^3$ or $x_i^2 x_j$ or $x_i x_j x_k$. Then summing these terms gives zero in all three cases.
For $l=4$ you can have $x_i^4$ or  $x_i^3 x_j$ or $x_i^2 x_j^2$ or  $x_i^2 x_j x_k$ or   $x_i x_j x_k x_m$. Then summing these terms gives zero in all cases where at least  one variable appears odd many times. That means, only the cases  $x_i^4$ and $x_i^2 x_j^2$ are nonzero, giving  $\sum_ {x_i = \pm a_i} x_i^4 = 2 a_i^4$, and $\sum_ {x_i = \pm a_i} x_i^2 \sum_ {x_j = \pm a_j} x_j^2 = 4 a_i^2 a_j^2$. Hence,
$$
\sum_ {\{x_i = \pm a_i\}} (x_1 + x_2  + \cdots + x_n)^4\\
 = 2^n \sum_{\begin{array}{c} i\\ k_i = 4; \; {\mathrm{other}} \; k_j =  0\end{array}} {4 \choose 0,0, \ldots, 4} a_i^4 + 2^n  \sum_{\begin{array}{c} i,j \\ k_i = 2; \; k_j = 2; \; {\mathrm{other}} \; k_m =  0\end{array}} {4 \choose 0,0, \ldots, 2, 2} a_i^2 a_j^2\\
= 2^n  \sum_i a_i^4 + 2^n \times 6 \sum_i \sum_{j > i} a_i^2 a_j^2
 $$
Continuing like this, you have zero for all odd $l$, and for even $l$ all arrangements in pairs must be considered with the mentioned multinomial coefficients.
E.g. for $l=6$ you have
$$
\sum_ {\{x_i = \pm a_i\}} (x_1 + x_2  + \cdots + x_n)^6\\
= 2^n  \sum_i a_i^6 + 2^n \times  {6 \choose 0,0, \ldots, 2, 4} \sum_i \sum_{j \ne i} a_i^4 a_j^2 + 2^n \times  {6 \choose 0,0, \ldots, 2, 2, 2} \sum_i \sum_{j > i}\sum_{k > j} a_i^2 a_j^2 a_k^2\\
= 2^n  \sum_i a_i^6 + 2^n \times 15 \sum_i \sum_{j \ne i} a_i^4 a_j^2 + 2^n \times  90 \sum_i \sum_{j > i}\sum_{k > j} a_i^2 a_j^2 a_k^2
 $$
Those formulae also hold in the case where $2n <l$. So if you have, for example,
$$
\sum_ {\{x_i = \pm a_i\}} (x_1 + x_2)^6\\
= 2^n  \sum_i a_i^6 + 2^n \times 15 \sum_i \sum_{j \ne i}  a_i^4 a_j^2 + 2^n \times  90 \sum_i \sum_{j > i}\sum_{k > j} a_i^2 a_j^2 a_k^2\\
= 4 (a_1^6 + a_2^6) + 4 \times 15 (a_1^4 a_2^2 + a_1^2 a_2^4) 
 $$
so the last term vanishes since $\sum_i \sum_{j > i}\sum_{k > j} $ is not available.

Understood (+1)!
